# 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I did all to solve this issue, most of advised Remove node_modules files, remove pod files, and then update node, React Native, and install fresh pod but still facing following issue.

```
'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
```

Also I noticed pod file came with no depdencies while it should added all react depedencies.

This is what my pod file looks like.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'pinnacle' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for pinnacle

end
```

Comment: could you share your react-native version

Comment: "react-native": "^0.62.2",

Comment: try to install Cocoa Pods globally

Comment: I did but it di not solve the issue